# Complex parametric plot in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Consider the complex variable `z = sqrt(x + a1 y) + sqrt(x + a2 y)` with `x > 0`, `y in R` real, and `a1,a2 in C` complex. I would like to produce a parametric plot of `Re(z)` vs. `Im(z)`. It should look something like this:

[image]

To my surprise, [searching this site for "complex parametric PGFPlots"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=complex%20parametric%20PGFPlots) didn't bring up anything.

Might be that's because (afaik) PGFplots has no notion of complex numbers and no functions `Re` and `Im` to isolate real and imaginary parts. So I was thinking about implementing the complex square root as explained by Did in [this post on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number) but that would be quite a hassle. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a go at this with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I've wrapped this in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) but you could easily adapt it for plain `mpost`.  I'm not sure it's a very robust solution, but it might form the basis for some further investigation.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
% assume the pair z is a complex number and return the pair corresponding 
% to the complex sqrt
def zsqrt(expr z) = dir 1/2 angle z scaled sqrt(abs(z)) enddef;

beginfig(1);
    numeric xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
    xmin = 0; xmax = 12; ymin = 1; ymax = 3;

    vardef f(expr x,y) = zsqrt((x,0) + (1,1) zscaled (y,0) ) + zsqrt((x,0) + (2,+2) zscaled (y,0)) enddef;
    vardef g(expr x,y) = zsqrt((x,0) - (1,1) zscaled (y,0) ) + zsqrt((x,0) + (2,-2) zscaled (y,0)) enddef;

    vardef edge_path(suffix FUN)(expr xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, s) =
        for x=xmin step  s until xmax: FUN(x,ymin) .. endfor
        for y=ymin step  s until ymax: FUN(xmax,y) .. endfor
        for x=xmax step -s until xmin: FUN(x,ymax) .. endfor
        for y=ymax step -s until ymin: FUN(xmin,y) .. endfor cycle
    enddef;

    path a, b;
    a = edge_path(f,0,12,1,3,1/4) scaled 1cm;
    b = edge_path(g,0,12,1,3,1/4) scaled 1cm;

    fill a withcolor .8[blue,white]; draw a;
    fill b withcolor .8[red+1/2green,white]; draw b; 

    path xx, yy;

    xx = (1/2 left -- 9 right) scaled 1cm; 
    yy = (7/2 down -- 3 up) scaled 1cm;  
    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Metapost has complex numbers weakly built-in.  You can basically treat a `pair` type as a complex number.  The built-in operations `abs` and `angle` work as you might expect, and the operation `zscaled` does complex multiplication.

### Edit

I have updated the complex sqrt function with a more correct, rather simpler, and more efficient version.  The original one was:

```
vardef sqrtz(expr zz) = 
    save c, r, w;
    numeric r, c;
    pair w;
    r = abs(zz);
    w = zz + (r,0);
    c = sqrt(r)/abs(w);
    w scaled c
enddef;
```

which is geometrically sound, but fails with negative real numbers.  The replacement is more robust and makes better use of MP's built-in functions.  The new one is:

```
def zsqrt(expr z) = dir 1/2 angle z scaled sqrt(abs z) enddef;
```

If you are treating pairs as complex numbers, then `angle z` gives you the argument, and `abs z` gives you the modulus.  `dir theta` gives a unit vector rotated theta degrees from (1,0), so `dir 1/2 angle z` gives you a unit vector with half the argument of `z`, which is then scaled by `sqrt(abs z)` which is what we want.

Note that if you try to do `angle (0,0)`, MP gives an error that says `! angle(0,0) is taken as zero`.  In this case this is what we want, but MP stops because of the error.  You avoid the error by writing this:

```
def zsqrt(expr z) = if z=origin: origin else: dir 1/2 angle z scaled sqrt(abs z) fi enddef;
```

which is probably the best general purpose function.

Comment: Looks good! I was really hoping for a solution in PGFPlots/TikZ though, since all the other graphics in my project were created that way.

Comment: Thanks.  Using `standalone` means you can produce a PDF that you could include, of course, but perhaps my answer will stimulate the PGFplots mavens to suggest a solution.